# How to make `NSViewController` a `@MainActor` and have it implement `NSMenuItemValidation`

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

I've a custom `NSViewController` subclass that implements the `NSMenuItemValidation` protocol. That works just fine, until I mark the view controller as `@MainActor`.

I believed Apple marked all view controllers as main actor isolated already, but maybe it does so only on iOS. But I thought it would be safe to mark my subclass as such.

Once I add the `@MainActor` line, I get the warning `Instance method 'validateMenuItem' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not satisfy corresponding requirement from protocol 'NSMenuItemValidation'`:

```
@MainActor
final class MyViewController: NSViewController, NSMenuItemValidation {
    func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
    }
}
```

Is it not okay to mark a custom `NSViewController` subclass as `@MainActor`? Or how should I deal with this warning?

I want to mark my view controller, because it needs to co-operate with other classes that are (explicitly) isolated to the main actor and I want to avoid various async boundaries that are totally not necessary, knowing the view controller will always run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You must mark the function w/ nonisolated. I'm assuming this is because the NSMenuItemValidation protocol is not restricted to the main queue.

`nonisolated func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool { }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this solves the warning it makes it 'impossible' to access any properties of the view controller. I then need to do that async but the function needs to provide the answer synchronously.